# Uncertain how to design django apps - best practices

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-models, django-apps

In every django app I've previously developed I used only one app, which had all models, forms etc included.
It was OK for small apps, but now it's time to do it right way :)

I want to have ***auth*** module which will cover such things like user signups, login, welcome email sending etc.

So... I've created app called 'auth'. In auth.models module I have something like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField()
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    time_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Team(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Team title'), max_length=64)   


class Member(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)

    USER_ROLES = (
        ('admin',_('Administrator')),
        ('member',_('Team member')),
    )
    role = models.CharField(_('User role'), max_length=6, choices=USER_ROLES, default='member')
```

Here comes my first trouble. Every user in my app will have one-to-one Member object. Member object stores some additional data about the user. Every single user must be assigned to group (which I call **Team**)... But wait... Should't be **Team** class moved to separated app which will manage Teams???

Also, I like to inherit all model classes from BaseModel. Do I have to add this same BaseModel class in every app again? Isn't a breaking "don't repeat yourself" rule?

Also, during registration of new user I need to create new Team for him. Where should I put code for this? Its related both to user management and team management.

I would need some guidance, how to fix these design issues.

Comment: Also - if you ever fancy discussing more "open-ended" Python/Django questions, feel free to pop over to the [Python chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python). There's usually people on there that can help you out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apps are intended to be self contained "modules" of code that could be reused in other django projects in the future. Ask yourself whether you'd ever want to re-use this code in another project.

Your extended user model, with teams would strike me as being part of a single app. You're not defining site-specific behaviour with respect to teams or members. I could also see many cases where you'd re-use the above code.